# how to insert flash into form like http://www.mediafire.com

Tags: php, jquery, css, flash

I would like to isert flash upload into my index file but I dont knoz how to insert flash. this is the link of the flash http://www.tinywebgallery.com/en/tfu/web_demo1.php  i would like to insert like http://www.mediafire.com when you click to UPLOAED to MEDIAFIRE . thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are explicit directions on the site:

http://www.tinywebgallery.com/en/tfu/web_install.php

> 1. Extract the content of the zip to a directory on your web space.
> 2. Change the permissions of the folder 'upload' to 777 (this is only
>      the folder for testing - I think you
>      will change this later ;))
> 3. Call tfu.htm. The example files should show up on the left side.

Once you follow these steps you can follow the set up instructions in the same page linked above.

Answer (score 0):

use dreamweaver and open inser menu select the common tab than select flash icon than select your flash file location its finish now you can see your flsh is in you index file and any where where you want to set it

Comment: Using a preset Dreamweaver method is a poor choice of methodology.

Comment: @ Syed Abdul Rahman i think its the best solution for new users what do you suggest for this work